# Area calculate, ln

Tags: calculus, area

Hey can someone help me with this area calculation?
I need to show that the area between the lines $y= 1/x$ and $y= x/2$ and $y= 2x$ equals to $ln 2$.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of integrals ?

Comment: Write function names such as trigonometric or logarithms with a backslash-prefix, so they become $LaTeX$ symbols and are rendered as function symbols in upright font instead of italics. like variables: `ln x` → $ln x$ but `\ln x` → $\ln x$,

Comment: Find the equation in polar coordinates $r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta =1 $  and use for required $ A = \int r^2/2\, d\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fistly,find intersection points of functions $$\frac { 1 }{ x } =2x\Rightarrow { x }=\pm \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } \\ \frac { x }{ 2 } =\frac { 1 }{ x } \Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt { 2 } $$
[image]

$$\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  }{ \left( 2x-\frac { x }{ 2 }  \right) dx } +\int _{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  }^{ \sqrt { 2 }  }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ x } -\frac { x }{ 2 }  \right) dx } $$
we have equal simmetric area so multply it $2$

> so the area is $$2\left[ \int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  }{ \left( 2x-\frac { x }{ 2 }  \right) dx } +\int _{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  }^{ \sqrt { 2 }  }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ x } -\frac { x }{ 2 }  \right) dx }  \right] =2{ \left( \frac { 3{ x }^{ 2 } }{ 2 }  \right)  }_{ 0 }^{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  }+2{ \left( \ln { x-\frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ 4 }  }  \right)  }_{ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  }^{ \sqrt { 2 }  }\\ =\ln { 2 } $$

Answer (score 0):

Switching to polar coordinates, the domain is

$$\text{arccot}\sqrt2\le\theta\le\arctan\sqrt2,\\\rho\le\frac1{\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}}.$$

Hence the area

$$\int_{\theta=\text{arccot}\sqrt2}^{\arctan\sqrt2}\int_0^{1/\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}}\rho\,d\rho\,d\theta=\frac12\int_{\theta=\text{arccot}\sqrt2}^{\arctan\sqrt2}\frac{d\theta}{\sin\theta\cos\theta}.$$

Then with $t=\tan\theta$,

$$\frac12\int_{1/\sqrt2}^{\sqrt2}\frac{dt}t=\ln2.$$